# What are the mantras recited in a Prana Pratishtha pooja?

Tags: mantras, temple, idols

I was reading about the opening ceremony of a temple, that mantras are recited to welcome the divine to reside in the Murti. What are the mantras recited?

Comment: Atharvashirsha.

Comment: @Pandya: Thank you, is this for only Lord Ganesha or any deity?

Comment: @AmitSaxena  I have posted one answer but it is not for temple but individual house. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/17947/7853