# How to do Prana Prathishta of Maa Kali Idol?

Tags: kali, pranapratishtha

I am preparing to do the [Prana Pratishtha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prana_Pratishtha) of maa kali idol. Please help me to Prana Pratishtha of Maa Kali Idol.

Comment: Permanent prana pratishtha or the daily temporary prana pratishtha?

Answer (score 2):

As you know that prAna pratistha means transferring and establishing the life force into the idol or sigil. As the name suggests, there should be an actual movement of prAna into the object.

To stimulate the flow of prAna, it is good to adopt a few yogic techniques. First of all, it is good to perform mahA-mudra for 5 minutes. Then one must start rhythmic breathing and continue for at least 15 minutes. It could be anuloma-viloma or any other mode of breathing.

Then one must be calm in order to feel the prana. One should shake the hands a few times and focus on the fingers and palm in order to feel the energy flowing. After shaking the hands a few times, one should hold them facing each other and gently bring them close and then move them apart and should feel the energy between them. The posture is given in the picture below.

[image]

You will start feeling some kind of energy or magnetic power in a few minutes. Then one must hold the hands in the form of anjali and hold the idol in it. Then one must mentally imagine goddess or focus on the idol (as it is the picture of goddess itself). After meditating for a few minutes, one should start feeling that the energy from your body is getting transfered to the idol via your palms and fingers. anjali posture of hand is as below

[image]

Imagine inhaling in energy as you inhale and imagine it going through your hand into the idol in a form of liquid light. Be calm and repeat the process at least for 30 minutes.

While holding the idol and energizing it, mentally repeat the following [mantra](http://www.astrojyoti.com/pranapratisthaofyantra.htm) along with your breathing. Imagine idol getting energized with the liquid light or prAna.

**Aim Hrim Shrim Om Am Hrim Kraum Yam Ram Lam Vam Sham Sham Sam Haun Ham Sah "may Life exist here in the idol!"**

**Om Am Hrim Kraum Yam Ram Lam Vam Sham Sham Sam Ham Ham Sah "my individual existence be here in the idol!"**

**Om Am Hrim Kraum Yam Ram Lam Vam Sham Sham Sam Ham Ham Sah  "may all the senses be here in the idol!"**

After this, if you wish then you can continue the process with chanting mantra of the goddess or simply her name. Finally request goddess establish the pranic energy in the idol and make it established in the idol.

Then you can place it in the pooja place and worship with some flowers, rice etc.

This is process given in a brief manner in order to make it simple. There are other detailed and more complicated procedures available too.

Comment: Sir, praan pratishta in itself is a vistrut vishay, but openly displaying Beejas in public domain is against Aagam dharma. I hope you abide to the integrity of a marga and please edit the beeja section. If needed just add reference, please.

Comment: Hello Rakesh, Does this sequence of Beeja mantras make sense? From what I see, **Yam Ram Lam Vam Sham Sham Sam Haun Ham Sah** (the part that is common in the three separate sections) are just sequenced to activate chakra 1-4 (from base to up), followed by sham (or Om for 6th chakra), followed by vibrating petles of last two chakras, this is in contrast to what I had expected, the sequence from lower to upper, where they seem to ignore middle one.

Answer (score 1):

## Introduction

Prana Pratishtha is a step of Puja. Just before Prana Pratishtha, Avahana is done. After, Prana Pratishtha, Sakalikaran (where nyasa is performed on the Murti's body)

Puja is an Agamic practice. However, it also uses Vedic Mantras and Puranic hymns. As the Vaishnavas, Shaktas and Saivas use different Agamas, the process varies a bit among different sects. Here I am writing the process according to the Sakta method.

One more thing to remember is that the process is the same for any god or goddess. You just have to use the specific name of the God or the Goddess. Here the Prana Pratishtha Mantra is for Goddess Kali. You have to just change the name depending on the deity you are worshipping.

## Step 1

The worshipper has to take flowers and Kusha in his right hand, and then touch the murti's head and do japa of the Veeja mantra of that deity 108 times.

## Step 2

> Having thus invoked (the Devi) into the Yantra, the Vital Airs of the Devi should be infused therein by the following Pratishtha Mantra. - *Mahanirvana Tantra 6.70*

If the Puja is performed with a Murti (idol), in that case, the worshipper should touch the Murti's cheek joining the thumb and the little finger of the right hand and say the mantra

> Ang, Hring, Krong, Shring, Svaha; may the five Vital Airs of this Devata be here: Ang, Hring, Krong, Shring, Svaha. Her Jiva is here placed – Ang, Hring, Krong, Shring, Svaha – all senses – Ang, Hring, Krong, Shring, Svaha. Speech, mind, sight, smell, hearing, touch, and the Vital Airs of the Adya-Kali Devata, may they come here and stay happily here forever. Svaha. - *Mahanirvana Tantra 6.71-74*

One has to use the name of the specific God or Goddess. For example, in the case of Dakshina Kalika, the mantra would be -

> aum hrīṃ kroṃ yaṃ raṃ laṃ vaṃ śaṃ ṣaṃ saṃ hauṃ haṃsaḥ śrīmaddakṣiṇakālikāyāḥ prāṇāḥ iha prāṇāḥ।

> aum hrīṃ kroṃ yaṃ raṃ laṃ vaṃ śaṃ ṣaṃ saṃ hauṃ haṃsaḥ śrīmaddakṣiṇakālikāyāḥ jīvaḥ iha sthitaḥ।

> aum hrīṃ kroṃ yaṃ raṃ laṃ vaṃ śaṃ ṣaṃ saṃ hauṃ haṃsaḥ śrīmaddakṣiṇakālikāyāḥ sarvendriyāni iha sthitāni।

> aum hrīṃ kroṃ yaṃ raṃ laṃ vaṃ śaṃ ṣaṃ saṃ hauṃ haṃsaḥ śrīmaddakṣiṇakālikāyaāḥ vāk‌ mana cakṣu staka śrotra ghrāṇa prāṇā ihāgatya sukhaṃ ciraṃ tiṣṭhantu svāhā।

One has to recite it three times.

## Step 3

Now one has to place the prana with the lelihana mudra.

> The person who knows the use of Mantras should invoke the spirit with the following mantras by putting his thumb (using lelihana mudra) on the heart of the icon and while reciting yajurmantra(see below) he should say this: let the spirit pervade this icon, let the spirit stay within it, let svāha bestow divinity on it. - *Kalika Purana 88.14-15*

The yajurmantra mentioned is the following

> मनो जूतिर्जुषतामाज्यस्य बृहस्पतिर्यज्ञमिमं तनोत्वरिष्टं यज्ञम् समिमं दधातु।
> विश्वेदेवासऽइह मदयन्ताऽमोम्प्रतिष्ठ।।

> mano jūtirjuṣatāmājyasya bṛhaspatiryajñamimaṃ tanotvariṣṭaṃ yajñam samimaṃ dadhātu।
> viśvedevāsa'iha madayantā'mompratiṣṭha।।

> The butter’s rapid flow delight his spirit! Brihaspati extend this act of worship. May he restore the sacrifice uninjured. Here let all Gods rejoice. OM! Step thou forward. - *Shukla Yajurveda 2.13*

After uttering this Yajurmantra, one should chant the mantra from Kalika Puran 88.15

> अस्यै प्राणाः प्रतिष्ठन्तु अस्यै प्राणाः क्षरन्तु यत्।
> अस्यै देवत्व संख्यायै स्वाहेति यजुरुच्चरन्।।

> asyai prāṇāḥ pratiṣṭhantu asyai prāṇāḥ kṣarantu ca।
> asyai devatva saṃkhyāyai svāheti yajuruccaran।।

> let the spirit pervade this icon, let the spirit stay within it, let svāha bestow divinity on it. *- Kalika Purana 88.15*

## Step 4

> Having recited the above three times, and having in due form placed the Vital Airs (of the Devi) in the Yantra with the Lelihana-Mudra (see step 3), with folded palms, he (the worshipper) should say: *- Mahanirvana Tantra 6.75*

> O Adya Kali! hast Thou had a good journey, hast Thou had a good journey? O Parameshvari! mayest Thou be seated on this seat? *- Mahanirvana Tantra 6.76*

References -

[Mahanirvana Tantra](https://www.globalgreyebooks.com/mahanirvana-tantra-ebook.html)

[Kalika Purana](https://archive.org/details/QCML_the-kalika-puran-translated-in-english-by-b-n-shastri-edited-by-surendra-pratap-nag-publishers-/page/n45/mode/2up)

[Yajurveda](https://www.globalgreyebooks.com/texts-of-the-white-yajurveda-ebook.html)

Comment: How good is it to display Beeja mantra so easily in public domain? These beejas may turn catastrophic for someone if referred. Thus, I'd request u to edit that portion and give mere reference.

Comment: @Chamundadas I do not agree with you.

Comment: Wow, maybe I'm wrong at this whole scenario, moderators may add their pov. The more the better.